# How can i get all English alphabet from a-z in js?Maybe someone know the method for this?

Tags: javascript, string

I know that in Python there is method to get alphabet. Is it exist in js?

As i said? i just want to get all english alphbet. That is all

Comment: You could be clever, but in real code, I'd probably do `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to generate the letters:

```js
const alphabet = Array.from({ length: 26}, (v, n) => String.fromCharCode(n + 97));
console.log(alphabet)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```